# BelongsToMany Relationship - Sequelize

Tags: node.js, api, rest, express, sequelize.js

I have a problem in the listing of records with belongsToMany association using sequelize + nodejs.

I have the developers and technologies tables. The relationship between them is many to many. To create a relationship, use a pivot table called developers_technologies.

Below is a gist with the code of: Models (developers, technologies), migration (developers_technologies) and controller of Developers.

https://gist.github.com/fredarend/85ff60fca70643d80301b499e871c4a6

The code of the Index of the controller Developer is this:

```
async index(req, res) {
const developers = await Developer.findAll({
  attributes: ['id', 'name', 'email'],
  include: [
    {
      model: Technologies,
      as: 'technologies',
      attributes: ['id', 'name'],
      through: { attributes: [] },
    },
  ],
});

return res.json(developers);}
```

Return:

```
[
    {
        "id": 25,
        "name": "Jon Doe",
        "email": "jondoe@gmail.com",
        "age": 27,
        "url_linkedin": "http://asdasdasd",
        "technologies": []
    }
]
```

I would like to know why I am not receiving technologies linked to the developer, since the developers_technologies table in the database is populated and the relationships in the models are ok.

EDIT:
query generated from the request:

```
SELECT 
"Developer"."id", 
"Developer"."name", 
"Developer"."email", 
"technologies"."id" AS "technologies.id", 
"technologies"."name" AS "technologies.name", 
"technologies->developers_technologies"."created_at" AS "technologies.developers_technologies.createdAt", 
"technologies->developers_technologies"."updated_at" AS "technologies.developers_technologies.updatedAt", 
"technologies->developers_technologies"."developer_id" AS "technologies.developers_technologies.developer_id", 
"technologies->developers_technologies"."technology_id" AS "technologies.developers_technologies.technology_id" 
FROM "developers" AS "Developer" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ( "developers_technologies" AS "technologies->developers_technologies" 
INNER JOIN "technologies" AS "technologies" ON "technologies"."id" = "technologies->developers_technologies"."developer_id") ON "Developer"."id" = "technologies->developers_technologies"."technology_id";
```

Kind regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to indicate `otherKey` in `belongToMany` associations. Also you indicated wrong foreign keys. For Developer it should be `developer_id` and for Technology it should be `technology_id`:

Model - Developer

```
this.belongsToMany(models.Technology, {
      foreignKey: 'developer_id',
      otherKey: 'technology_id',
      through: 'developers_technologies',
      as: 'technologies',
    });
```

Model - Technology

```
this.belongsToMany(models.Developer, {
      foreignKey: 'technology_id',
      otherKey: 'developer_id',
      through: 'developers_technologies',
      as: 'developers',
    });
```

Comment: I added, the same return continues: /

Very strange..

Comment: look at generated SQL query and add it to your question